# ember data and dealing with 404

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

There have been questions about this topic in previous years, but Ember has changed a lot since then and most of those answers were fill ins until things were more 'together'.  I am working on an app that is using ember-cli.  On the api, if you request a resource from the api that does not exist, the api returns a 404.  However, ember data seems to just throw an error upon receiving a 404.

I saw one approach that seemed promising, someone answered a similar question in 2014 and had this code sample:

```
return this.store.find('matter', params.matter_id).then(
        (function (_this) {
            return function(model){
                resolve(model);
            }
        })(this),
        (function (_this) {
            return function(invalid){
                _this.transitionTo('auth.denied');
            }
        })(this));
```

ember promises can take a resolve and reject as arguments.  In the above code, he passed self instantiating functions as the resolve and reject arguments.  The reject is working just as I would like it to.  However, now the issue that I am running into is that when I am in the resolve, even though the 'model' variable comes back with an ember data object, i cannot seem to get this to resolve properly. Ember throws and error stating, "Expected an object as `data` in a call to `push` for matter , but was undefined".

I was hoping someone out there in the Ember community might have some insight in either how to get this to resolve properly, or perhaps a better way to approach this problem altogether.

Comment: resolve isn't defined there...

Answer (score 0):

`this.store.find` returns a  [promises](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_find).

Try doing something like

```
this.store.find(...).then(function(model) {
  console.log(model);
  resolve(model)
}, function(reason) {
  alert('error');
});
```

Is the model `json`, if not it's probably the problem?